# which one is correct? Killing the innocence "within" or "inside"?

Tags: word-choice

Killing the innocence "within" or "inside"?
When talking about inherent qualities of someone, should we use "inside" or "within"?

Comment: For intangible objects, I'd prefer *'within'*. An evil within me. For the tangible ones, I'd prefer 'inside'. The bullet is *inside* his body. So, here, 'within'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For things like innocence or beauty or other characteristics, they are usually said to

> **come from within** *( a person's spirit or being )*
>
> beauty comes from **within**
>   change comes from **within**

**Inside** would imply there is a specific place these things are kept inside of one.

> the pain **inside** my stomach means I'm hungry

**Within** has a more general meaning of location, spread through one's body.